# add effect on image view

Tags: android, effect

I want to add effect on image when clicked, I want transperent effect not any colour.

here is my code.

```
`<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="282dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivcontactfb"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:src="@drawable/fb"
                 style="@style/DefaultButton"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivcontacttw"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tw"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" 
                style="@style/DefaultButton"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivcontactin"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:src="@drawable/in"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                style="@style/DefaultButton"/>
        </LinearLayout>`
```

[image]

help me for this please,
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the effect when you click on it you should probably use a `ImageButton` instead of a `ImageView` and set it up like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ivcontactfb"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:src="@drawable/imageview_states"
    style="@style/DefaultButton"/>
```

and create a custom xml file in your drawable resources:

**drawable/imageview_states.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/media_icon_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/media_icon_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/media_icon_selected"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/media_icon_default"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: my image doesnot sets in the image button thats why i have used the image view...

Comment: is there any way to use effect for image view?

Comment: Uhm why doesn't it set in the imagebutton?

Comment: You could try to do the same with the ImageView.. Set a background and use the same drawable resource. Don't know if it works for a ImageView

Comment: my image is circular in shape and if i apply effect on it then it becomes square...

Comment: thats why I am not using the image button.... first is image button and other 2 are image view...

Comment: instead of setting the background. Set the source of the image as the imageview_states.xml here you can specify the different states

Comment: will get the button in circular shape? by your edited answer?

Comment: depends on what image you upload.. You should design a circular icon yourself and when the image is pressed the image doesn't warp into a circular shape it just replaces the rectangular one with the circular